# Input validation check

Tags: javascript, css, validation

In my website I have a forum, and I want to avoid cross site scripting. Do you know a good input validation script?

Comment: Validation should (and must) be done server-side. You can't trust javascript. Which server language do you use?

Comment: @Keeper - the absolute and agreed necessity to do server-side validation does not prohibit doing client-side validation *as well*.

Comment: @annakata - You're right. The question was about avoiding XSS and I was pointing out that javascript is not the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to avoid Cross Site Scripting.

1. Filter the inputs by the users
   (mainly script tags and html tags)
   both at client side as well as on
   server side.
2. Display the contents as
   Html entities to avoid Cross Site
       Scripting. Ofcourse if you want to show some
       of the tags, go for option one.
       Otherwise option two is more
       reliable.

You can use regular expressions to filter the data both on client side as well as on server side.

Comment: Both the methods mentioned above are language independent. In python you have a good regex support with 're' module to filter the contents.

Comment: If you are using Django with appengine it automatically escapes the HTML enities by default.

Answer (score 1):

I've always relied on the OWASP PHP filters: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters As you can tell from the name, they're server-side (JavaScript or HTML5 validation is only useful for assisting the user) and OWASP (the Open Web Application Security Project) is a non-profit organisation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where do you want to write out the data. For example you need different filter when you write the text into an input field and when you write it simply into the html body, between two tags.

You should implement different filters for the different data types on server side. I suggest you should filter the text when it's printed out, and not when the user sends it to you(of course it's not about sql injections and other server side tricks), because (as I mentioned above) the type of the filter you should use is depends on where the data is printed out.

If you want to write a really simple forum, then it's enough to write only one filter, wich simply removes all html tags from the text before it's printed out. Beware, it's not good for advanced functions, for example edit comments, when you prefill a form for the user, or if the users can use any html tag in their comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Make sure you escape the HTML from your input object before using it. This way, the data sent will be treated as raw text. The way to do this will be to pass the input through some parser before embedding the data in your page (or working with it somehow).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with anand that there are two major ways to avoid XSS: validation on input and escaping on output. For validating form input, tie into Django's Form Validation Framework: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html

Here are some code samples for sanitizing on output within a Django templating. Instead of this:

```
Welcome, {{ firstname }}!
```

Do this:

```
Welcome, {{ firstname|escape }}!
```

This is from this very good blog post: http://startupsecurity.info/blog/2008/10/28/avoid-xss-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

You have two option for validation. for non-sensitive data client side JavaScript may be use.
in JavaScript, you can write simple function for validating your data.

for sensitive data, you should be use server side scripting like, php,jsp,asp,asp.net etc.

may this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Check more string functions you need to validate

**Client Side**

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

better to write your own jquery code, in future it may help you